# Jython fails to load modules having 'com' as top level namespace

Tags: python, jython, jython-2.7

I have a Jython module `com.xyz.module1` in Jython site-packages directory. The directory structure is below.

```
Jython2.7
|---Lib
    |--site-packages
        |--com
            |--__init__.py
            |--xyz
               |--__init__.py
               |--module1
                  |--__init__.py
```

When i try to import `com.xyz.module1` in Jython interpretor, `ImportError` is thrown ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL1u5.png)). However, import works fine when i rename `com.xyz.module1` to `foo.xyz.module1`.

I have read [Jython doc](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html#proper-python-naming) which discourages (but does not forbid) the use of `com` as top level module namespace. Also the Jython library i am interested in cannot be refactored not to use `com` as top level namespace.

Is there any other way to make the import to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. There is an unresolvable conflict here between the way Python import works and the way people name Java packages.

Perhaps this is overly simplistic, but the first 'com' encountered during import will be the one and only 'com', and will prevent the second 'com' from being imported.

So, you need to take a different approach when naming your Jython (Python) packages.